# Book series involving a teenage girl whose mother doesn't let her leave the house, until the day her mother disappears and two men attack the house

Tags: story-identification, novel

I think I got this as a Kindle book, might have had more than one book in the series (and I'm pretty sure it was a series). The girl's mother never let her leave the house, and is constantly training her in martial arts and survival skills. I think when her mother is out of the house, she's required to stay inside a refrigerator-size box in the basement for her own protection. One night, while her mother is out, her house is broken into by two men with supernatural powers (extremely strong and tough, I think) and in the process of escaping them, she escapes the house. Not long after that, she gets hooked up with some secret society out to protect humanity with other people with powers trying to hurt people (or maybe just grab power). The girl, of course, has her own sets of powers. I want to say that it's revealed that all of these powers come from mythological ancestry, with the girl being descended from the Greek line. I also want to say there was someone with Gorgon or Medusa ancestry, although I don't remember if they were good guys or bad guys.

I don't have a firm idea on when I read this. I think it was part of a bunch of books I got for free from a site like Plenty Of Ink, basically promotional copies in hopes that you buy later entries in the series. That would like put them about 7 years ago. I don't think it was less than five years ago, because I'm remembering it as an early acquisition.

Comment: I can't find any sites called "Plenty of Ink" that do free ebook samples.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Let me poke around my email and see if I have any receipts.

Comment: And nothing matching a name like that in that time period... maybe they just gave me an Amazon link? Nonethless, that may give me some keywords to search in my email.

Comment: Could this be "The Girl in the Box?"

Comment: That actually looks very likely. Do you want to post that as an answer.

Comment: No, I don't have time to read it right now, so I don't want to see anymore spoilers for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per NomadMaker's comment, this is the *[The Girl in the Box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016DEKFTC)* series by Robert J. Crane.

> Sienna Nealon was a 17 year-old girl who had been held prisoner in her own house by her mother for twelve years. Then one day her mother vanished, and Sienna woke up to find two strange men in her home. On the run, unsure of who to turn to and discovering she possesses mysterious powers, Sienna finds herself pursued by a shadowy agency known as the Directorate and hunted by a vicious psychopath named Wolfe, each of which is determined to capture her for their own purposes...

Reading through the reviews, it's about metahumans, which have been popping up among humanity for a few thousand years, but nothing explicitly mythological. I may have to do a reread to see if anything else is stated.