# Novel (probably a Kindle eBook) about an alien who possesses someone working a retail job (coffee shop?) who hates the body and his job

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I was reading through some recent story-id queries when I suddenly had a book I read, probably a good decade ago, run through my head, or at least as much as I read at the time. My wife had pointed me towards a website that provided links to Kindle books that were currently free (the same site I referenced [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240639/book-series-involving-a-teenage-girl-whose-mother-doesnt-let-her-leave-the-hous)), and one of them was this book, which started with an alien stopping a human on the road and forcibly taking over their body for... some reason. I don't remember if they were scouting Earth for an invasion, doing the tourist thing, or hiding, but they took over this guy's body with the twist being that, in doing so, they found themselves stuck, and wound up taking over his life, including his dead-end job, I think at a coffee shop. My vague memory of it is that the person he took over hated their life with such a passion that it had infected the alien and they just couldn't muster the effort to escape the body.

For some reason, I want to say that title was something about aliens and hipsters and that the cover (which I think was indeed to an eBook) was predominantly white, maybe with a shot of the alien's head in dark colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it's not a perfect match I'm guessing this could [The Hipster from Outer Space](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28434205-the-hipster-from-outer-space) by Luke Kondor.

[image: The Hipster from Outer Space]

> An ancient space-being called Moomamu has awoken on Earth and wants nothing more than to get back to his home in the stars. Taking the advice of his cat, Gary, he makes his way up t’north to meet the Tall-One-With-Insight.
>
> As he journeys across a land of underground trains, cappuccinos, and a man obsessed with killing him, he soon learns that being on Earth is a symptom of a bigger problem, and going home, just might destroy the planet.

The cover and title match, and the plot is broadly similar though Moomamu does not seize someone's body - he just wakes up in a human body.

Moomamu doesn't hate the human body. In fact he (it?) seems fairly chilled about the whole experience. However the serial killer Aidan does hate his body and fantasises about being a superior being. He chants a mantra to himself:

> "I'm sixty foot tall and made of diamond," Aidan muttered under his breath. "I'm sixty-fucking-foot tall and made of unbreakable diamond."

This may be what you are remembering. He has a menial job selling animal feed at a petting farm.

Comment: I do see that one in my library, and it does look close enough that my brain might have gotten muddled over the years. Thank you.